# VueJs bind boolean values to dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dropdown with two options: "True" and "False", when selected, I want the form to save the selected value as a boolean.

So if I check the form value when the user has selected "True", I want the value to be `true` as a boolean.

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option :value="null">Pick a value</option>
  <option v-for="val in options">{{val}}</option>
</select>

...

data() {
 return {
  selected: null,
   options: ["true", "false"]
}
```

Here is a fiddle of what I am attempting:
https://jsfiddle.net/q0nk9h32/5/

How can I output the selected values in their boolean form?

Bonus question: Instead of having the `options` variable, is it valid syntax / good practice, to do:

`v-for="val in ["true", "false"]"` ?

It seems overkill to have a variable for this (but it fails in fiddle when I try using an array directly). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a value to each `<option>` using `:value`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select-Options

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            selected: null
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
    <select v-model="selected">
        <option :value="null">Pick a value</option>
        <option v-for="val in [true, false]" :value="val">{{val}}!!!</option>
    </select>
    <p>
        Selected is the {{ typeof selected }}: {{ selected }}
    </p>
</div>
```

You can write the array for a `v-for` inline if you want. In your original example it wouldn't have worked because you included double quotes around your strings but were already using double quotes around the attribute.

You've got lots of options for rendering the text as `True` and `False` for these values...

If you just have two values, `true` and `false`, I'd be inclined to drop the `v-for` altogether and just write them separately.

```html
<option :value="null">Pick a value</option>
<option :value="true">True</option>
<option :value="false">False</option>
```

Alternative ways of formatting the text would be to use a filter or method. So that's:

```html
<option v-for="val in [true, false]" :value="val">{{ val | filter }}</option>
```

or

```html
<option v-for="val in [true, false]" :value="val">{{ method(val) }}</option>
```

For a filter you'd define it in your component's `filters` section, for a method it'd be in your `methods`. Either way the function just needs to convert the boolean value to a string and then uppercase the first letter.

```js
// Obviously you wouldn't call it 'method'...
method (value) {
    const str = String(value);
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}
```

That said, given there are only two possible options, there are all sorts of other ways to do it. e.g.:

```html
<option v-for="val in [true, false]" :value="val">{{ val ? 'True' : 'False' }}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks! My only issue here is that I need "True" and "False" to be a string when displaying it to the user, because I need a capital T and F respectively. Any suggestions?

And yeah, I just gave a small example to see how it would work. If it's just true/false, it does not need v-for

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a computed property that just returns this.selected === 'true'.